# Bash - Math: Returns integer instead of float

Tags: bash, shell, shell-scripting

Bash returns value `4` instead of `4.2` when dividing `21/5`. And returns `36` when doing `9 * (21/5)` instead of `37.8`.

```sh
echo "$(( 21/5 ))"
4
    
echo "21/5" | bc
4
```

Similarly `9 * ( 21/5 )` returns `36` but it should be `37.8`;

```sh
y = 9;
num_lines = 21;
w = 5;

let value="$y * ($num_lines/$w)"

echo $value
36
```

Comment: Bash's arithmetic expansion does not support floating-point calculations. Look at [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40786/381289) for other possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like this

```
$ echo "21/5" | bc -l
4.20000000000000000000

$ echo "$y * ($num_lines/$w)" |bc -l
37.80000000000000000000
```

For setting up limit of decimal point use like below, For 2 decimal point

```
 $echo "scale=2; $y * ($num_lines/$w)" | bc -l
 37.80
```

For 3 decimal point, just change the scale number.

```
$ echo "scale=3; $y * ($num_lines/$w)" | bc -l
37.800
```

Comment: nice. Is there a way to limit decimal points?

Comment: found it. echo "scale=2; 21/5" | bc -l

Comment: is I possible to do something like this? `while [ "$y" -le (( $y * ($num_lines/$w) | bc -l )) ]`

Comment: use like this `while [ $y -le $(( $y * $num_lines/$w | bc -l )) ];do echo 1; sleep 3;done`